# Update Values in Nested Dictionary According to Nested Key

Tags: nested, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following Structures:

```
MyDict = {'Team1': {'John' : 0, 'Mary' : 0},
          'Team2': {'Steven' :  0, 'Gwen' : 0,'Fred' : 0},
          'Team3': {'Louise' : 0, 'Alice' : 0, 'Jim' : 0},
          'Team4': {'Paul' : 0, 'George' : 0},
          'Team5': {'Tracey' : 0}}

MyList = ['John', 'Gwen', 'Jim', 'George', 'John', 'Gwen', 'Alice', 'Frank', 'John', 'Gwen', 'Frank', 'John', 'Gwen', 'Tracey']
```

The first is a nested structure with members in specific teams.

For each occurrence of the member in MyList, I need that value updated in MyDict.

Once complete, I need the printed total for each team.

So after iterating through MyList, the nested structure will look like this:

```
MyDict =   {'Team1': {'John' : 4, 'Mary' : 0},
            'Team2': {'Steven' :  0, 'Gwen' : 4,'Fred' : 0},
            'Team3': {'Louise' : 0, 'Alice' : 1, 'Jim' : 1},
            'Team4': {'Paul' : 0, 'George' : 1},
            'Team5': {'Tracey' : 1}}
```

And the printed totals will look like this:

```
Team1: 4
Team2: 4
Team3: 2
Team4: 1
Team5: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use code below:

```
MyDict = {'Team1': {'John' : 0, 'Mary' : 0},
          'Team2': {'Steven' :  0, 'Gwen' : 0,'Fred' : 0},
          'Team3': {'Louise' : 0, 'Alice' : 0, 'Jim' : 0},
          'Team4': {'Paul' : 0, 'George' : 0},
          'Team5': {'Tracey' : 0}}

MyList = ['John', 'Gwen', 'Jim', 'George', 'John', 'Gwen', 'Alice', 'Frank', 'John', 'Gwen', 'Frank', 'John', 'Gwen', 'Tracey']

for name in MyList:
    for key,val in MyDict.items():
        if name in val:
            val[name]+=1

for key,val in MyDict.items():
    print(key,':',sum(val.values()))
```

have fun :)